# Restore only data with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have notice, that when i am trying to restore DB, it is restoring DATA + Stored Procedures.  I want to restore only data from my existing database in sql server 2008, how can i achieve this.

*Scenario is*
I have Production DB and Development DB, while developing i have made several changes to SPs and Table Structure.  My file which i am using to track those changes is lost and now i want all Table Structure + SP's change in DB, and should also have latest data from production DB.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do a selective restore.

You have to restore the backup to another "work" database and then migrate the bits you want to recover into the target database. After that, you're free to drop the work database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following two tools, one to sync your objects and the other one to sync your data:

[ApexSQL Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx) – a SQL Server database comparison and synchronization tool which detects differences between database objects and resolves them without errors. It generates comprehensive reports on the found differences and can automate the synchronization process between live and versioned databases, backups, snapshots and script folders

[ApexSQL Data Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_datadiff.aspx) -  a SQL Server data comparison and synchronization tool which detects data differences and resolves them without errors. It can compare and sync live databases and native or natively compressed database backups and generate comprehensive reports on the detected differences

Disclaimer: I work as a Product Support Engineer at ApexSQL