# how to restore the database only for some specific data in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database with many tables. This database is used for save all transaction data from branch company. But now, I have a problem with 1 branch company concenrs data transaction. For example, I have table master about branch company with primary key is `BranchID ('BR01','BR02','BR03')`. Everyday my Application will create backup database.

Now, I want to restore data only for branch 'BR02', because that problem was fatal. 
Anyone, can you help me to fix my problem??

Comment: Checkout this thread would be help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685119/restore-only-data-with-sql-server-2008


Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a new database, restore the backup to this new database and then grab the data that you need from this new database to update the data in your original database

Answer (score 0):

---

Here is your answer:

Create a new table, lets say TestTable, and fetch values from **YOUR TABLE** to **TESTTABLE**. Hence, it will create a new table with your required data of BR02.

```
SELECT * FROM [your existing table]

SELECT *

INTO TestTable

FROM [your existing table]

WHERE BranchID = 'BR02'

----Verify that Data in TestTable
SELECT * FROM TestTable

GO
```

Best luck !